# c# asp.net javascript function not working

Tags: javascript, c#, html, asp.net, webforms

I want to have an alert confirmation box and display the price for the user to see, however, the alert is not coming not, not sure where I went wrong. Please help

This is the method i tried.

This is the javascript

```
<script>
    function showCFMRenewPlan() {
        var renewedPlanPrice = document.getElementById("renewedPlanPrice_HD");
        return confirm('Do you want to renew your plan for $' + renewedPlanPrice.innerHTML);
    }
</script>
```

This is my button and the hiddenfield im displaying the price.

```
<asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="renewedPlanPrice_HD" />
<asp:Button class="btn-primary btn-md" Font-Size="Medium" runat="server" ID="renewPlanButton" CausesValidation="false" OnClientClick="showCFMRenewPlan()" OnClick="renewPlanButton_Click1" Text="Renew Plan" />
```

in c# backend i added this to set the value of my hidden field

```
renewedPlanPrice_HD.Value = Convert.ToString(planPrice);
```

Comment: JavaScript only sees the rendered HTML, not the server-side controls/code.  What is the resulting HTML for these controls?  In the browser's debugging console are there any errors at all?  When you debug in the browser's debugging tools is this function invoked at all?

Comment: Check that the generates ID of the hidden field really is `renewedPlanPrice_HD`. Depending on your settings, ASP.NET may generate its own element IDs for the final markup. Check the generated HTML source, using your browser's Developer Tools.

Comment: @David what do u mean?

Comment: @ADyson how do i check?

Comment: @anonymous: Now is a great time to open your browser's debugging tools and start familiarizing yourself with them.  They are an essential tool for any web development.  In those tools you can observe the actual live HTML of the page, check for error messages thrown by JavaScript code, debug that JavaScript code, etc.

Comment: @anonymous `how do i check` ...read my comment again, I told you exactly how to check. If you've never used the Developer Tools before, you need to learn about them, so that you can operate effectively as a web developer. In most browsers, you hit F12 to open them. All the major browser vendors provide tutorials. The bit you need for this task is the element inspector, and possibly the Console. Alternatively, to inspect downloaded HTML you can use the good old View Source option which is present in every browser since the dawn of time (it's a separate tool, in Chrome hit Ctrl+U to open it.)

Comment: @anonymous P.S. If you're asking how to check whether your ASP.NET application is set to use static client IDs or not, it's a setting in your web.config (but can also be overridden at page or element level as well). See this blog for an overview of the feature: https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2009/nov/07/clientidmode-in-aspnet-40

Comment: @anonymous P.P.S. What David means is that `<asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="renewedPlanPrice_HD" />` is never seen by the Javascript. That's server-side ASPX markup, which acts as an instruction to ASP.NET about what kind of HTML it should generate when preparing a web page to send to the browser (in response to a request). e.g. `<asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="renewedPlanPrice_HD" />` is likely to be turned into something like `<input type="hidden" id="renewedPlanPrice_HD"/>` (but maybe not exactly that, depending on your aforementioned settings) which is valid HTML that browsers read

Comment: Try the following in your Javascript code:
var renewedPlanPrice = document.getElementById("<%= renewedPlanPrice_HD %>");